# Name of the Paladins' weapons?

Tags: jumper

In the 2008 film, Jumper, the Paladins use an electrified cable weapon to incapacitate jumpers, was this weapon ever given a name?

Comment: Meh, sounds like a pretty trivial question. Don't think it warrants a close, though, but definitely -1.

Comment: @ChristianRau - specialist in-universe objects are usually named (lightsaber, BFG-1000), though I realize it might not have a name (electro-wire shooter is descriptive at best).

Comment: Yeah, so what? I mean, who cares how this thing's named? It isn't that *Jumper* was settled in a highly complex and thought-through universe comprising multiple stories, movies and books, anyway. So the writers probably just thought *"who cares"*, too.

Comment: A more interesting question would be: _How did the Paladins catch Jumpers before the invention of electricity_ (according to Griffin they have been catching Jumpers "since medieval times")

Comment: @Oliver_C - excellent question, I'll ask if no-one else does, it's not too speculative?

Comment: @ChristianRau, at a guess, SteB cares how it's named, and that's why he/she asked the question.  If trivial questions are off-topic here, the whole site will have to be closed.  It's about *movies*, for Pete's sake.

Comment: @Kyralessa Yeah, and movies are always trivial, right? But nevermind.

Comment: @TomCody, well, mankind did manage to survive without them until the last hundred years or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jumper Wiki](http://jumperverse.wikia.com/wiki/Paladin#Power_Stick) describes the weapon as a "Powerstick", probably not canon, but it's better than referring to it as "that electricity weapon".

The same wiki page describes the Paladin's (unnamed) jump-scar-opening machine as a "Scar Ripper".