# How did Samuel L. Jackson come to know that Hayden Christensen was a jumper?

Tags: plot-explanation, jumper

How did Roland come to know that David is a [*Jumper*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489099/)?

And also which kind of electronic gun or machine was he using to catch the jumpers?

Comment: As to your second question, see here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/10510/49

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book [Jumper: Griffin's Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumper%3a_Griffin%27s_Story_%28novel%29), which was created *after* the movie but is intended to be a *prequel* to it, discusses this issue.

It states that Paladins can sense jumpers and close in on them as long as they are close enough to sense the jump taking place.

We don't know how many Paladins there are, but given they were aware of David's robberies, it appears they kept a keen eye out and simply "detected" him at some point. Not a great explanation, but it's the best *canon* explanation out there.